# Choosing a Deep Learning model to analyse microscope images

Tags: deep-learning, image-processing

I have lots of simulated training data of microscope images and I want to train a network to count the number of points in the image.  These points are distributed in concentric oblate shells. The foreground and background ones are out of focus. I don't need the positions of the crystals. I'm having some success but wondering if I can do better. My network has three groups of conv2d (3x3)->Relu-> BatchNormalization-> MaxPool layers, with the second having a dropout layer. These propogate into two conventional 512 relu layers with a drop out in between, before being collected into a single neuron in the final layer. I scale the output of this to between 0 and Max count.

I'm just not sure this is the appropriate model as I took it from a object detection task, and I know they account for the same object at different distances, whereas mine are all taken at the same distance. If they appear bigger, it's because they are! It's taking about a day to train with 600K training set. I also wonder if the 3x3 filters are too small, and would like something that takes into account the shape of the shells.

If anyone has any suggestions, or look at this, it's a similar problem or that's insane try anything else I'd really be grateful as I need some inspiration and I don't think longer training is it!